# How to simply store some files

Tags: ios, file

I'm developing an app which needs to show some logos. These logos are just 8kb PNG files, and I'm just going to handle a little amount of them (10-20 at most). However, these are downloaded from the Internet because they might change. So, what I'm trying to achieve is, making the app to download them (done), storing them into the file system, and only downloading again whenever they change (might be months).

Everyone seems to use Core Data, which in my opinion is something designed for bigger and more complex things, because my files will always have the same name plus don't have relations between them.

Is the file system the way to go? Any good tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the file system is probably your best option for this.  You say that you've already implemented the downloading.  How have you done so?  With `NSURLConnection`?  If so, then at some point, you have an `NSData` object.  This has a couple of [`write`...](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a) methods you can use to save the data to a file on the filesystem.  Be sure to save the files [in the right place](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW12), as your app is sandboxed and you can't write anywhere you like.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage Core Data brings is efficiency. Using NSFetchedResultsController to display your logos in a tableview gets you optimized object loading and memory management. It will automatically load only the items which can be displayed on one screen, and as the user flicks through the table it will handle releasing items which move offscreen. Implementing that on your own is not a simple task.

If you want to build and display your data without Core Data, you'll probably want to use NSKeyValueCoder, which will allow you to easily write an array or dictionary of objects (including nested arrays, dictionaries, and images).

Comment: That's pretty overkill, isn't it?  He's talking about 10-20 8KB PNGs at most, they rarely change, and he doesn't mention table views anywhere.  It's almost certainly going to be more efficient and convenient for him to store them as files.

Comment: @Jim The moment you exceed one screen of info, any solution which automatically releases non-visible images is going to be more efficient memory-wise. While he said they are 8KB PNGs, he didn't say what the resolution was. If they are 1024x768 PNGs heavily compressed, they'll still take up 1024 x 768 x 4 bits of memory _each_.

Comment: The fact is that I'm really using the images on a tableview, but the tableview will host 10-20 of them, and they are 48*48 PNGs. No Core Data needed here, right?

Comment: I would use it, only because it will speed up development and make it trivial to add more functionality to the app later if it becomes necessary (which in my experience is very often). You don't loose anything by using Core Data here, but you gain quite a bit.